# PGFPlots ! Undefined control sequence. \pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This is related to [a question I asked earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378646/skip-row-in-pgfplots-table-based-on-third-variable), in which I was trying to select rows of data based on the value of an unplotted variable. Following the answer to that question, I'm using "x expr" and "\thisrow" to determine which rows should be included.

However, I'd like to use the code in a \foreach loop, as in the below (which is not a full MWE, since I don't include the data. If the data seem necessary, I will add some examples). I keep getting the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@
```

which, based on questions in StackExchange, seems to happen for a variety of reasons related to macro expansion. Any idea how to avoid this error in this case?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\newcommand{\dir}{n:/pathtodata}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\outcomestest}{
  attn/Attendance,
  enrollall_00/Enrollment,
  all_mth00pctprof_00/Math Proficiency,
  all_rla00pctprof_00/Reading Proficiency}



\foreach \outcome/\label in \outcomestest{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-30,ymax=30,title=\label, xlabel=Year]
      \draw [red](axis cs:-4,0) -- (axis cs:2,0);
      \addplot table [x expr={\thisrow{bias}==1?nan:\thisrow{period}},y=b]{\dir/main_\outcome_primary.txt};
      \addplot table [x expr={\thisrow{bias}==0?nan:\thisrow{period}},y=b]{\dir/main_\outcome_primary.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I seem to have solved this on my own by inserting "    \pgfplotstableread{\dir/main_\outcome_primary.txt}\datatable" after the \begin{tikzpicture}, then referring to the file as \datatable in the \addplot command. I have no idea why that worked, but I'll take it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is solved by the OP in comments and the question doesn't include enough information to reproduce the error, so is not very likely to be of more general use.

Comment: @PaulB can you write an answer if possible?

Comment: I'd like to second the recommendation to post an answer (and clarify the question) instead of closing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP has solved it himself as mentioned in the comments. (And it doesn't seem that he is writing an answer ...)